# Windows 7 doesn't start up after updating

Tags: windows-7, boot, repair

I updated my Windows 7 32-bit machine, but after some restarting it doesn't even start up, i.e. it doesn't show the desktop screen. I tried to repair it using "Start up Repair" but it can't fix the problem. I also tried the following command in "system recovery options" > command prompt:

```
X:\Sources>bootrec /fixmbr
```

and

```
X:\Sources>bootrec /fixboot
```

but no changes occurred. It even doesn't go to the safe mode! Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: re install windows.

Comment: Is it the only solution? And what after that, don't updating the windows this time?

Comment: it takes 40-60 mins to reinstall windows, i could take up to x amount of hours/days for someone to give you an "answer" that probably won't even help you. Reinstalling windows 7 won't delete any of your data just move everything an windows.old folder. Also you must of turned off your computer while updating or something, updating your windows should never be a problem. you just had bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try System Restore, if you haven't disabled it. Windows automatically creates a restore point before installing an update. Since you can not acess Windows, you can use the install DVD or press F8 before the "Starting Windows" screen comes up and select "Repair Your Computer".

If you need more help, you can read [this tutorial at SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/668-system-recovery-options.html).

Comment: Thank you Araer, I had to re-install the Windows. At the first time the download source was in a folder on desktop (offline updating). But this time I'm going to use the source folder which is on a flash memory. I think the problem of the previous case was this that the source was in desktop on C:\ drive where the OS is also there and therefore the updating files also sit in there.